# how can I include arabxetex to texlive package

Tags: texlive, installing, arabxetex

I would like to install arabxetex package. I have already installed arabtex with command line sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-arabic. However I can't find a similar command for "arabxetex". Is there a command or a manual way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found "arabxetex" is included by "xetex" package. Therefore, we have to install xetex. If you are using debain-ubutu , you just type:

> sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is completely correct. I just want to add that in case you have problems *locating* the correct package, use `apt-cache search`, as in `apt-cache search arabxetex`, which will return you `texlive-xetex - TeX Live: XeTeX and packages`, after which you can call `apt-cache show texlive-xetex` to see the list of included packages.